# JavaFX/Spring custom onViewChange method

Tags: java, spring, user-interface, javafx

I am using a Spring Application, using JavaFX. I have created a static class that allows for changing views easily.

Now I require to call a method on a given view when it exits (similar to `initialize` method when view is summoned). Many views can call many others, so It hardly seems efficient to call such a method whenever I call SpringFxmlLoader separately.

Is there a way I can call a custom `beforeWindowChange` on currently loaded controller, and then load new view? That, provided there is no already existing method on JavaFX for this.

I can make sure this `beforeWindowChange` exists on every view controller of my project withouth issue.

My custom loader class:

```
public class SpringFxmlLoader {
    /**
     * Generic Window Loader for Project Overrides Controller Factory for Spring
     * and JavaFX Integration
     *
     * @param applicationContext - Spring application Context
     * @param anchorPane - Active view container.
     * @param resource - FXML loaded resource.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void changeWindow(ApplicationContext applicationContext, AnchorPane anchorPane, URL resource) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(resource);
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);
        // todo: get currently loaded controller from anchorPane
        // todo: call onWindowChange custom method
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public class SpringFxmlLoader {
    /**
     * Generic Window Loader for Project Overrides Controller Factory for Spring
     * and JavaFX Integration
     *
     * @param applicationContext - Spring application Context
     * @param anchorPane - Active view container.
     * @param resource - FXML loaded resource.
     * @throws IOException
     */

    private static final Map<Parent, Object> controllers = new HashMap<>();

    public static void changeWindow(ApplicationContext applicationContext, AnchorPane anchorPane, URL resource) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(resource);
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);

        Object controller = controllers.get(anchorPane);
        if (controller != null) {
            // do what you need to do with the controller...
        }

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

        controllers.put(anchorPane, fxmlLoader.getController());

        Stage stage = (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Note that your approach in general is not very Spring-like. Instead of using a static method, why not make your `SpringFxmlLoader` a singleton (the default) Spring bean, and then use instance methods and fields instead of static ones?

```
// not sure how you are configuring Spring, but with annotation-based
// configuration it would look like
@Scope("singleton") // not really needed as this is the default
@Bean
public class SpringFxmlLoader {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext ;

    /**
     * Generic Window Loader for Project Overrides Controller Factory for Spring
     * and JavaFX Integration
     *
     * @param anchorPane - Active view container.
     * @param resource - FXML loaded resource.
     * @throws IOException
     */

    private final Map<Parent, Object> controllers = new HashMap<>();

    public void changeWindow(AnchorPane anchorPane, URL resource) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(resource);
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);

        Object controller = controllers.get(anchorPane);
        if (controller != null) {
            // do what you need to do with the controller...
        }

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

        controllers.put(anchorPane, fxmlLoader.getController());

        Stage stage = (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Then of course you can just inject the `SpringFxmlLoader` wherever you need it.